# selectors via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to write the following code working with innerHTML in the compact platform-independent way (probably using jquery)?

The point is that IE names tags in different case in innerHTML, so I need two if clauses to handle that. toLowerCase does not help when it comes to quotes.

```
var flagpos = html.indexOf('</a>')
if (flagpos == -1) flagpos = html.indexOf('</A>')

html = (flagpos >= 0) ?
  '<span class="' + html.substr(flagpos + 4).
  replace(/^\s*|\s*$/, '').
  replace(/ /g, '"></span><span class="') +
  '"></span>' + res + ' ' + html.substr(0, flagpos + 4) : res + ' ' + html
```

-- or --

```
if (!toggleFlags[j] ||
    child.innerHTML.indexOf('<span class="' + j + '">') >= 0 ||
    child.innerHTML.indexOf('<SPAN class=' + j + '>') >= 0) continue
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [String.search()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) instead of [String.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to make your patterns case-insensitive (since you don't need an offset): `var flagpos = html.search(/<\/a>/i);`

what's stopping you from doing `$html = $(html);` and using the jQuery Traversing API?

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
var whoCares = child.innerHTML.toUpperCase();
```

Then you can always compare with UPPER CASE tag names.  (Or, use ".toLowerCase()" instead.) Of course that'll convert *all* the alphabetic characters to upper case (or lower case,  as the case may be), so you'll have to do:

```
if (!toggleFlags[j] || child.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf('<SPAN CLASS=' + j.toUpperCase() + '>'))
```

Yet another totally different approach is to stop looking for elements via the raw (or, rather, reconstituted) HTML, and use a selector (which maybe was the point of your question :-):

```
if (!toggleFlags[j] || child.find('span.' + j).length > 0) {
  // whatever
}
```